# LibreOffice Writer Styles

Tags: 13.04, libreoffice, layout, style

Is there anyway to easyly manage styles on LibreOffice Writer ? For instance, by installing a add-on ?

When I was using Word, it was really intuitive to use differents styles, manage them and edit them. When I want to make a nice page layout, I use the style function with `F11`, but it is not really instinctive.

Answer (score 2):

You could try by using **Next Style** function. For example, lets say you have a *Header 1* followed by some *Text body*. When setting up a *Header 1* style (right click on line and then choose **Paragraph style**), choose tab **Organizer** and in and then for **Next Style** choose *Text body*. Further on, after writing a line in Header 1 and pressing enter, LibreOffice Writer should by default switch itself to Text body. As far as I know, there are no MSWordish big icons for that purpose.